# SQL Select random from multiple table and order by specific criteria on one table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to select a random record from 3 tables and ensure I am ordering by photoOrder

```
Select TOP 1(a.id), a.mls_number, a.parcel_name, a.property_type, a.ownership_type,     b.filename, b.photoOrder, c.county_Name
From property as a
Inner JOIN
listingPhotos as b on a.id = b.ListingID 
LEFT JOIN
counties as C on a.county_name = c.id
WHERE a.isCommercial = 'True'
Order By NEWID()
```

So this query works, but I need to ensure that the b.filename record is ordered by b.photoOrder and thus the b.photoOrder should always be 1.
The b table (listing photos) has multiple photo files per property and I need to only select the photo that is 1st in the photo order.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could subquery your listingPhotos table and limit to WHERE PhotoOrder = 1:

```
Select TOP 1(a.id), a.mls_number, a.parcel_name, a.property_type, a.ownership_type,     b.filename, b.photoOrder, c.county_Name
From property as a
Inner JOIN
(SELECT ListingID , filename, PhotoOrder FROM listingPhotos WHERE PhotoORder = 1
       ) as b on a.id = b.ListingID 
LEFT JOIN
counties as C on a.county_name = c.id
WHERE a.isCommercial = 'True'
Order By NEWID()
```